# Need to set a background image from the server for splash screen in Xamarin (ios and android)

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin, splash-screen

I have a Xamarin Forms project and now I need to change my splash screen background image. The image needs to get from a web server and set for ios/android. How can I do it?

Comment: on iOS (And probably Android too) the launch image is fixed as it is displayed before any code starts running.  You could make your initial view in your app fetch an image from a server and display it.

Comment: Splash screen should not delay using of the app. Trying to download image from the server will delay your app's startup even more. You wasting time of your users by making them wait till your image loads from server to show on splash screen